# Python's subprocess.Popen() results differ from command line?

Tags: python, bash, cygwin

Using Cygwin on Windows 7 x32, in a VS solution directory, the `find` command produces correct results:

```
$ find . -iname "*.sln"
./ProjName.sln
```

but the same command with Python's `subprocess.Popen()` seems to be matching on `*` alone:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.Popen(['find', '.', '-iname', '"*.sln"'],
...     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
.
./.git
./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
./.git/config
./.git/description
<snip>
```

What's wrong with my`Popen()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.Popen(['find', '.', '-iname', '*.sln'],
...     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False).communicate()[0]
```

Note the removal of double quotes around `*.sln` and the setting of `shell` to `False`.

This makes sure that the `*.sln` is passed to `find` verbatim and is not expanded by the shell.

**edit:** The following also works:

```
>>> print subprocess.Popen(['find . -iname "*.sln"'],
...     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: I had deleted my first comment. `shlex.split()` will remove the quotes around the pattern, but I'm still not sure why `shell=True` causes a full match.

Comment: @wes: I've been experimenting with this further, and it seems that `shell=True` requires the command to be specified as a single argument. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX systems, when you use `Popen(['find', '.', '-iname', '"*.sln"'], shell=True)`, Python does this:

```
/bin/sh -c find . -iname "*.sln"
```

If you read the documentation for `sh`, you'll find that only the first argument after `-c` is treated as a command string to be executed as a shell script. The remaining arguments are actually treated as arguments *to the shell script*. In this case, as the shell script consists solely of the command-name "find", the arguments are ignored. You can observe this behaviour if you run:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['echo arg0 = $0, arg1 = $1', 'foo', 'bar'], shell=True)
arg0 = foo, arg1 = bar
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
print subprocess.Popen(['find . -iname "*.sln"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```