# Python - execute find with multiple conditions using Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'd like to execute `find` with multiple conditions, for example: find **foo** excluding hidden files:

```
find . -type f \( -iname '*foo*' ! -name '.*' \)
```

Python code:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["find", ".", "-type", "f", "(", "-iname", "*foo*", "!", "-name", ".*", ")"]
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print sp.communicate()[0].split()
```

Can somebody explain what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: btw, with `os.path.walk` you can easily implement a pure Pythonish walk, without external subprocessing

Comment: I'm having this same problem, even without the exclusion of hidden files.

Comment: What error do you get? You should use `-print0` and `.split('\0')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well, and I'm sure you've figured this out by now but I figured I'd weigh in just in case anyone else runs into the same issue.  Come to find out, this happens due to what Python is actually doing when you use Popen (When shell=True is used, python is basically just using /bin/sh -c to pass in your command ([Python's subprocess.Popen() results differ from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231074/pythons-subprocess-popen-results-differ-from-command-line)).  shell is False by default, so if you omit this or set it to False, whatever is specified in 'executable' will be used.  The docs go into more detail here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Something along these lines should work

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'find . -type f -iname "*foo*" ! -name ".*"'
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print sp.communicate()[0].split()
```

Comment: `Popen` does *not* run `/bin/sh` unless you ask for it using `shell=True`

Comment: I've clarified that based on your comment.  This still works afaik.

Comment: the code in the question works as is. You don't need `shell=True`

Comment: Strange -- my code blows up if I omit shell=True.  `dir_list = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` then calling wait for the exit code, `out, err = dir_list.communicate()
` and returning out.   *Edit* Just found out our server is using 2.6.6 -- I'll edit this if updating to 2.7 fixes my issue.

Comment: you should use a list argument e.g., `shlex.split(cmd)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I'll give that a try (after I upgrade python)

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.7 subprocess.run() you can drop splitting cmd on spaces into a list, string will do just fine.

Nothing in the documentation though [subrocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

I was unable to get a command expanded into a list to work, while the string worked fine.

```
cmd = "find . -type f -iname \*foo\* ! -name .\\*"
print(cmd)
ret = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(ret)
```

Testing:

```
$ find . -type f -iname \*foo\* ! -name .\*
./foobar.txt
./barfoo.txt

$ ./findfoo.py
find . -type f -iname \*foo\* ! -name .\*
CompletedProcess(args='find . -type f -iname \\*foo\\* ! -name .\\*',
 returncode=0, stdout=b'./foobar.txt\n./barfoo.txt\n', stderr=b'')
```

Answer (score -1):

at least, need to escape the *'s there.

at second either escape the ( and ) by backslash (pass the "\\(" and "\\)" to shell)

```
cmd = ["find", ".", "-type", "f", "\\(", "-iname", "\\*foo\\*", "!", "-name", ".\\*", "\\)"]
```

or even just get rid of those ( and ) -

```
cmd = ["find", ".", "-type", "f", "-iname", "\\*foo\\*", "!", "-name", ".\\*"]
```

should work just fine